# iOS app, identical functionality and codebase, different UI

Tags: ios, user-interface, app-store, submit

I have a situation where the app functionality required is identical for a number of clients. The clients, for marketing purposes, wish to have the app completely rebranded in their own respective company colors - which means different launch icon, display name, skins etc.

From a code perspective, this is fairly easy to handle, but from an App Store perspective, I am a little uncertain about whether each version needs to be submitted to Apple as a separate app or is there a way to submit a single version to the App store which embodies the different UI variations

Thanks

Comment: You need to ask a question. This is a question and answer web site.

Comment: Each app will have to be submitted as its own app. As once it is in the app store there is know way for the app to know which brand to use. Unless you are happy leaving the icon the same for each brand and you let the user choose which brand they want after launch.

Comment: does each app needs to have its own URL on the app store (by this i mean if a UI change implies to have a different app in the app store) or is it a single app in the app store that changes according to a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that's not doable is the icon. Apps on the App Store are not allowed to change their icon.

Comment: Does the launch icon on the iphone have to be identical to the icon in the app store? Or can I install a different launch icon on the iphone determined by some external parameter eg. scanned QR code

Comment: unfortunately no, one icon per app. You upload your icon to the store along with your app.